# Tiva C Dio driver with AUTOSAR method

Tags: c, driver, dio, autosar

My graduation project's part is DIO driver for Tiva C MCU with AUTOSAR, I have no idea where and how to start. Are there any useful sources/materials that could help me implement such a thing given that I know nothing about the AUTOSAR methodology or ARM (Tiva C) configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is the autosar.org, where you'll find e.g. the AUTOSAR_SWS_DIO.pdf and AUTOSAR_SWS_Port.pdf, which define the APIs you need to implement and also in chapter 10 defines the parameters for configuration. And you need something to generate the configuration.

Then there is the Tiva MCU reference manual, which you'll need to understand, how to implement within the Dio functions to set/get the status of a DioChannel or a DioChannelGroup.